# Valor de uma variável texto fazer selecionar um item do Select em javascript

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho uma variável

var texto que recebe valores pré determinados, e quero que o valor selecione o item do campo select

exemplo:

```
var texto = 'Volvo';



<select>
   <option value="1">Volvo</option>
   <option value="2">Saab</option>
   <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**A variável recebeu Volvo quero que seja selecionado Volvo do Select.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode percorrer os options e quando o texto for o mesmo, selecioná-lo (explicações no código):

```js
var texto = 'Mercedes';

// seleciona as options do select
var opts = document.querySelectorAll("select option");

// laço que irá percorrer o select
for(var x=0; x<opts.length; x++){

   // verifica se encontrou o texto
   if(opts[x].textContent == texto){

      // se encontrou, seleciona
      document.querySelector("select").value = opts[x].value;
      break; // aborta o laço, já encontrou
   }
}
```

```html
<select>
   <option value="1">Volvo</option>
   <option value="2">Saab</option>
   <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

O `.textContent` pega apenas o texto dentro do elemento.

Com jQuery você pode fazer de uma forma um pouco mais simples usando o seletor **[.contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)**, que vai direto ao elemento sem a necessidade de laço:

```js
var texto = 'Audi';

$("select option:contains('"+texto+"')")
.prop("selected", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
   <option value="1">Volvo</option>
   <option value="2">Saab</option>
   <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dessa forma:

**Código JS + JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var texto = "Mercedes";
    var exemplo = $("#test").find("option:contains('" + texto + "')");
    exemplo.attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

**Trecho do HTML**

```
<select id="test">
   <option value="1">Volvo</option>
   <option value="2">Saab</option>
   <option value="3">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="4">Audi</option>
</select>
```